# How to disable logging to the .mysql_history file

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, history, debian-buster

I have a debian 10 system. When I set the rights 400 and 000 to the / root folder and to the .mysql_history file, they are ignored or reset when exiting mysql. Thus, I can’t disable logging in any way, I need the correct way to disable logs, restrict recording to several files in the root folder

Comment: you can disable loggong in the my.xnf or my.ini by default only slow query log and error log is enabled.

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'slow_query_log' shows off. These are not the logs that are related to the .mysql_history file which records all commands entered through the terminal.

Comment: see here https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/disable-mysql-history-clear-mysql_history-and-mysql_histfile/ this also poits the hispory file to dev null https://sxi.io/clear-mysql-command-line-history-stored-in-mysql_history-file/

Comment: I found a better page https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql-command-line-client/#the-mysql_history-file. Nothing to comment if you can answer

Comment: they all say the same, but what ever works

Comment: The official documentation is more understandable, but in the article I broke my leg and bent my back

Answer (score 0):

I set the shell variable MYSQL_HISTFILE to /dev/null. That's the right decision